# Find average of list + 2 inputs - python

Tags: python, list, loops, average

I need to find the average of 5 assignments = two inputs. I'm getting a result, but its no correct. Here is what I have:

```
def main():

  # list of grades
   x = []

   # count of students 
   n = 5

   # fill list with grades from console input
   # using pythonic generator
   x = [int(input('Please enter the grade you got on assignment {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(n)]

   midTermGrade = int(input('Please enter the grade you got on you Mid-Term: '))
   finalGrade = int(input('Please enter the grade you got on you Final: '))

   average_assignment_grade = sum(x) + midTermGrade + finalGrade / 7 

   print('Avg grade is ', average_assignment_grade)

main()
```

As you can see here, the math is wrong, the average suppose to be around 28, not 114

[image: Python Console]

Comment: You have to enclose the whole expression of addition with parentheses. Operator precedence and PEMDAS, ie `(sum(x) + midTermGrade + finalGrade) / 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with order of operations. You need to change:

```
average_assignment_grade = sum(x) + midTermGrade + finalGrade / 7
```

to:

```
average_assignment_grade = (sum(x) + midTermGrade + finalGrade) / 7
```

You can read about Python operator precedence [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Answer (score 0):

Karin's answer is correct. Python uses [BEDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), and that is why you didn't get the expected result.

---

However you're using Python 3. The [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) was added in Python 3.4; it has the [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function that will calculate the mean (or "average"):

```
from statistics import mean

average_assignment_grade = mean(x + [midTermGrade, finalGrade])
```

The rationale behind this function is that it is not prone to many rounding errors:

```
>>> a = 100000000000000000.0
>>> sum([a, 3.0, -a) / 3
0.0
```

but

```
>>> statistics.mean([a, 3.0, -a])
1.0
```